# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow, cuda

This is not a duplicate question! I have seen related questions and none of the answers there helped. So I am asking here.

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu. When I try to import it, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

even when I have set up the environment variables:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/home/ank/bin:/home/ank/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$ pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the global environment variable

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You need to show where you installed your cuda. [Take a look at this](https://ai-pool.com/d/importerror_libcublas_so_9_0)